AssertJ JUnitSoftAssertions how to wait for page to load
I am using JUnitSoftAssertions and I like it so far. But sometimes, the click on call-to-action button takes longer than the next assertion, so it causes test failed.
For example:
@Rule
public final JUnitSoftAssertions softly = new JUnitSoftAssertions();

@And("he should be on {page} page")
public void gotoPage(String page) {
  // current page is A, click to go to page B
  toPageBButton.click();
  softly.assertThat(driver.getCurrentUrl()).as("Page B").isEqualTo(page);
  softly.assertAll();
}

Assertion is failed because getCurrentUrl() is still on Page A.
If I am in debug mode, then it passes, because I have breakpoint.
If I assert that a button on Page B is displayed before the isEqualTo(page), then it also passes, but it is strange that I assert a button before I assert current URL
Is there any way to wait before the click action and assertion? I would not want to use Thread.sleep()

Since I use WebElementFacade, so I can wait until the button is not visible anymore, after the click:
toPageBButton.click();
element(toPageBButton).waitUntilNotVisible();

